# Why I can't call "toUpperCase()" on a "String?" variable?

Tags: dart

The following produces a compilation error:

```
String? str = null;

print(str.toUpperCase());
```

But why is that, I mean isn't using `String?` instead of `String` means that I can work with the `null` value?

Comment: Because `null` doesn't have a `toUpperCase` method.  If you want calling `toUpperCase` to do nothing if `str` is `null`, then use `str?.toUpperCase()`.  Or if you really want a runtime error if `str` is `null`, then use `str!.toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

The point of static null safety is to avoid runtime errors.

In pre-null-safe Dart, you could write `String s = null; print(s.toUpperCase());` and get a runtime error.

In null-safe Dart, you cannot. Because the variable can contain `null`, it must be typed as `String? s = null;`.
You *cannot* call `toUpperCase` on `String?`, aka. "`String` or `Null`", because `Null` doesn't have a `toUpperCase`.

You need to promote the value from `String?` to `String` before you can call `String` methods on it. You can do that in many different ways, which can be generalized to two: Those which throw if the value is `null`, and those which take a different path (other than throwing) if the value is `null`, so you won't call the method on `null`. You then have to do something else on the other path.

The most common ways to call methods on a nullable value are:

Throwing ones:

- `print(s!.toUpperCase());`. The `s!` throws if `s` is `null`, and otherwise it has type `String`, so you can call `toUpperCase` on it. That simulates the pre-null-safety behavior of checking for `null`, and throwing if you find it. The `!` here is called the "null check operator".
- `print((as as String).toUpperCase());`. Same as `s!`, just with more steps.

Non-throwing:

- `print(s?.toUpperCase());`. The `s?.toUpperCase()` calls `toUpperCase` on `s` *only* if `s` is not `null`. If `s` is `null`, it *doesn't* call anything, and the result is again `null`. Luckily `print` accepts `null` as an argument, so you can print it. This is called a "null aware method invocation".
- `print(s == null ? null : s.toUpperCase())`, pretty much the same as `s?.toUpperCase()`, just with more steps. Relies on promotion, and therefore only works on local variables.
- `if (s != null) print(s.toUpperCase());`. Also relies on promotion, so only works if `s` is a local variable. Always a good choice, just not always the shortest one.
- `if (s is String) print(s.toUpperCase());`. The longer and slower way to do the same thing as `!= null`.

Or if you really want to throw, and also want to do everything yourself:

- `print(s == null ? (throw "Null Bad!") : s.toUpperCase());`.

All in all, you need to promote to non-`null`. There are lots of ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You stated the issue yourself, because it could be a null value you can't make it upper case because you can't make null upper case.

Comment: But I am using `String?` and not `String`, so wouldn't this mean that I can call `toUpperCase()` (which of course would produce a runtime error)?

Comment: You are using `String?` meaning that it might not be a string, it could be null. You can't call `toUpperCase()` on a null value. Try just declaring and not setting the strings value, for example `String str;` and use that instead of setting it to null.